# Copy SQLite db to Storage device for backup purpose

Tags: android, sqlite, backup

I have an application in which I am updating my SQLite db file, but every time when the user uninstalls this application this db file is deleted and at reinstallation a new db file is created. I want to copy this db file after every update to a micro SD card so that after uninstallation I could be able to access my database.

Goal 
Copy every time when db file is updated

1. say text.db when created
2. now I want to copy this db file to micro SD card
3. this db file (application db file) is being updated
4. now copy and replace this db file to micro sd card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo code to copy the database to SD-Card. To copy it back, simply reverse the streams.

```
         public boolean copyDatabase() {
            String SDCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            // Create the directory if neccesary.
            File directory = new File(SDCardPath  + <PATH TO SD-CARD SAVE LOCATION>);
            if (!directory.exists())
                    directory.mkdir();


            // Close the database before trying to copy it
            database.close();

            // Copy database to SD-card
            try {
                    InputStream mInput = new FileInputStream(<PATH TO DATABASE ON PHONE>);
                    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(SDCardPath + <PATH TO SD-CARD SAVE LOCATION>);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = mInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            mOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    mOutput.flush();
                    mOutput.close();
                    mInput.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            return database.open();
    }
```